# Using lookup list in Teradata (Using Teradata SQL Assistant)

Tags: sql, external, teradata

I'm new to Teradata.  I have a table with millions of records and I am trying to query based on a subset using a lookup list to feed my where clause.
My lookup list contains thousands of records.

In SQL Assistant this is what I've tried:

```
SELECT  T.*
FROM a_balance T
JOIN
    OPENROWSET (
             BULK 'c:\myfile.txt',
             FORMATFILE = 'c:\myfileformat.txt'
    ) B ON T.accountID  = B.accountID
```

What would you recommend to do in Teradata SQL Assistant?

Comment: Try importing the data into a table.

Comment: I don't have write access to the database.

Comment: You don't need write access to the same database as the a_balance table.  ask for a write access in any database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @denoeth suggested -
You can create a **volatile** table.
(I would still suggest you'll ask for a scratch/playground database)

> **VOLATILE**
>   ...The definition is of a volatile table is retained in
>   memory only for the duration of the session in which it is defined.
>   **Space usage is charged to the login user spool space**. Because volatile
>   tables are private to the session that creates them, the system does
>   not check the creation, access, modification, and drop privileges. A
>   single session can materialize up to 1,000 volatile tables.
>
> SQL Data Definition Language Syntax and Examples Release 15.10
>   B035-1144-151K June 2015

---

**Import using Teradata SQL Assistant**
(Good for relatively small sets of data)

> "Tools" -> "Options" -> "Import"

set/unset "Ignore the first record in the import file (Skip Header)"
Set "Maximum Batch size for simple import" to 999

```
create volatile set table accounts (accountID int) 
unique primary index (accountID) 
on commit preserve rows
;
```

> "File" -> "Import Data"

```
insert into accounts (accountID) values (?);
```

> "File" -> "Import Data" (cancel selection)

Comment: Of course this also works without Create Table rights using a Volatile Table :-)

Comment: @denoeth - Touché :-)

Comment: Better add `ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS`, most customers run Teradata mode sessions :-) And switch to `SET` to avoid duplicate row errors.

Comment: @dnoeth - SET tables are the devil :-)

Comment: @dnoeth - P.s. Thanks for the lesson :-) I've missed the (non) privileges aspect

Comment: This worked great in getting the data in.  Now I just need to figure out the join.  My latest attempt (left join) gave me all the rows *except* the ones I wanted.

Comment: 1) Good to hear. 2) Please open a new post for this question